# Trilogy about magic rocks that grant magic powers

Tags: story-identification

I know it’s an older series; I believe the publication date was around the '80s or early '90s.  The main focus of the books are these magic rocks granting certain powers (lightning, truth seeking, damage absorption—I believe—etc.), and the original stone found is called something like "lamb shabah." It’s all set in early medieval times era. I think it’s called the "Lightning [something]," but I know it’s not *The Lightning Thief*. After the main character finds the first stone and starts to use it, her main arm (I think her left one) gets heavily scarred; however, the other stones don’t leave as bad marks on their users. Any help identifying what book series this is, or who the author is, will be greatly appreciated, as I would love to read it again. Thanks.

Comment: See OP confirmation comment below.

Answer (score 3):

possibly  Holder of Lightning (The Cloudmages #1) by S.L. Farrell

[See if this looks familiar](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176754.Holder_of_Lightning)

While I do not specifically remember scaring and the date does not match it was the first thing to come to mind when I read lightning and magic stones with the stones having proper names.

Comment: That’s it exactly! Thank you so much, I’ve been trying to remember that for so long